# How to override django wagtail joyous

Tags: django, wagtail

How to add a field or override model from joyous? I try extend like wagtail models but doesnt work.

```
class CustomCalendarPage(ProxyPageMixin, CalendarPage):

    @route(r"^all/$")
    def serveAll(self, request):
        """all events list view."""
        myurl = self.get_url(request)
        today = timezone.localdate()
        monthlyUrl = myurl + self.reverse_subpage('serveMonth',
                                                  args=[today.year, today.month])
        weekYear, weekNum, dow = gregorian_to_week_date(today)
        weeklyUrl = myurl + self.reverse_subpage('serveWeek',
                                                 args=[weekYear, weekNum])
        listUrl = myurl + self.reverse_subpage('serveAll')
        allEvents = self._getAllEvents(request)

        eventsPage = self._paginate(request, allEvents)
        cxt = self._getCommonContext(request)
        cxt.update({
            'weeklyUrl':    weeklyUrl,
            'monthlyUrl':   monthlyUrl,
            'listUrl':      listUrl,
            'events':       eventsPage
        })
        cxt.update(self._getExtraContext("all"))
        return TemplateResponse(request,
                                "joyous/calendar_list_all.html",
                                cxt)
```

I want add a view where list all events (past and future)
Thanks!